# Counting combinations between two Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I'd like to re-format a dataframe such that it shows the counts of combinations of two columns. Here's an example dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['first', 'second', 'first', 'first', 'third', 'first'],
               'b': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],
               'c': ['do', 're', 'mi', 'do', 're', 'mi'],
               'e': ['this', 'this', 'that', 'this', 'those', 'this']})
```

which looks like this:

```
        a    b   c      e
0   first  foo  do   this
1  second  foo  re   this
2   first  bar  mi   that
3   first  bar  do   this
4   third  baz  re  those
5   first  baz  mi   this
```

I want it to make a new dataframe that counts combinations between columns `a` and `c` that would look like this:

```
c        do   mi   re
a                    
first   2.0  2.0  NaN
second  NaN  NaN  1.0
third   NaN  NaN  1.0
```

I can do this using `pivot_table` if I set the `values` argument equal to some other column:

```
my_pivot_count1 = my_df.pivot_table(values='b', index='a', columns='c', aggfunc='count')
```

The problem with this is that column 'b' could have `nan` values in it, in which case that combination wouldn't be counted. For example, if `my_df` looks like this:

```
        a    b   c      e
0   first  foo  do   this
1  second  foo  re   this
2   first  bar  mi   that
3   first  bar  do   this
4   third  baz  re  those
5   first  NaN  mi   this
```

my call to `my_df.pivot_table` gives this:

```
first   2.0  1.0  NaN
second  NaN  NaN  1.0
third   NaN  NaN  1.0
```

I've gotten around using `b` as the `values` argument for now by setting the `values` argument equal to a new column I introduce to `my_df` that is guaranteed to have values using either `my_df['count'] = 1` or `my_df.reset_index()`, but is there a way to get what I want without having to add a column, using only columns `a` and `c`?

Comment: Use `len` like `df.pivot_table(values='b', index='a', columns='c', aggfunc=len)`?

Comment: great example of a good pandas question, BTW. the time you put into it is apparent.

Comment: `count` counts non-null values by default. By passing a `values` parameter you are asking it to count the non-null values in that column. You don't need that. Use `size` and don't pass any values: `my_df.pivot_table(index='a', columns='c', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Seems there are many options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.crosstab` has a `dropna` argument, which by default is set to `True`, but in your case you can pass `False`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['a'], df['c'], dropna=False)
# c       do  mi  re
# a                 
# first    2   2   0
# second   0   0   1
# third    0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `groupby`/`unstack` for this:

```
df.groupby(by=['a', 'c']).size().unstack(level='c')

c        do   mi   re
a                    
first   2.0  2.0  NaN
second  NaN  NaN  1.0
third   NaN  NaN  1.0
```

You can get fancy with `fillna` and `astype`

```
N = (
    df.groupby(by=['a', 'c'])
      .size()
      .unstack(level='c')
      .fillna(0)
      .astype(int)
)

c       do  mi  re
a                 
first    2   2   0
second   0   0   1
third    0   0   1
```

Comment: `unstack` has a `fill_value` parameter which you can set to 0. That handles casting as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.fillna('x')` after `my_df` without changing the base dataframe itself.

```
my_pivot_count1 = my_df.fillna('x').pivot_table(values='b', index='a', columns='c',aggfunc='count')
```